# Does CASino (ruby CAS server) have any way to create users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cas

I have the CASinoApp server running with an ActiveRecord authenticator.

I have a client application using omniauth-cas.

My problem is that I don't know how users are created for CASino to leverage.

That is, I am presented with a login screen (username, password), but I have no idea how that data should be populated. Do I need to create my own forms, controllers, etc to populate the CASino users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, CASino is intended to leverage an existing user table.

This URL right here https://github.com/rbCAS/casino-activerecord_authenticator/issues/11 shows a developer using CASino to handle authentication on top of an existing Devise Users table.

To create a user, you would still go through Devise, but to handle SSO authentication, you would go through CASino.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the point of a CAS server? Unless you use Devise on the server side? but then does the app have a user model?